# İ cant post form send mysql for update

Tags: php, html, css

i create form and submit button and create button=save but no send update all mysql table and db true please check my code where i can wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ob_start();
session_start();

  try{
       $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=repair;charset=utf8','root','password');
   }catch(PDOException $e){
     echo 'Hata: '.$e->getMessage();
   }
$menusorgu = $db -> query("select * from setting");
$menucek = $menusorgu-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="setting_title"value="<?php echo $menucek['setting_title']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="setting_id" value="<?php echo $menucek['setting_id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save">
  </form>
  <?php

if(isset($_POST['save'])) 
 {

$sql = "UPDATE setting SET setting_title = :setting_title, WHERE setting_id= :setting_id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':setting_title', $_POST['setting_title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->execute(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: What about that `filmID`? Where do you get it from? Don't you want to bind it too?

Comment: Hi! based on your DB image I dont see any column called "filmID" in your DB. So it does not update because it does not find any filmID column first. and then no line for your where

Comment: i now edit film id but already not runnig

Comment: I just rearranged the codes
please check again

Comment: You may need an action in your form except if you manage it with JS. and as mentionned, how do you get your settings_id ? You may need to add an hidden input

Comment: man I don't really know how to do it, can you show it

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="setting_id[]">
should I create it this way? but it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, so the name has changed from `filmID` to `setting_id`. Where do you get `setting_id` from? Why do you bind `:setting_title` but not `:setting_id`? Have you tried turning on error reporting to see what the issue is?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/u1dvb4
I delete the 28th parameter but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

So here is the direct link to php form: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

You may find some interesting basic. But in your case, I will say that you should at least add a file to your action, to send your form to your controller.

As you choose the method post, I will recommand to add a hidden input to include your setting_ID:

```
  <form role="form" action="YOURCONTROLLER.PHP" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="setting_title" value="<?php echo $menucek['setting_title']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="setting_id" value="<?php echo $menucek['setting_id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save">
  </form>
```

I dont think it would solve all, but at least you will have a base

Comment: If the action is empty it uses the current page URL.

Comment: still not working, i'm going crazy
Why would a simple line of code not work?

Comment: @Barmar Yes sure, but that is not the safe way.

Comment: You seem to be saying that it's related to the problem, not an unrelated recommendation.

Comment: @juniordev4444 what do you have if you `dump(isset($_POST['save']));die;` ?
@Barmar yes you right to correct, this is why I gave you 1+

Comment: I tried moving php files to a different file and running it failed !!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/u1dqmu    I did everything you said none happened
I don't understand what is so difficult

Comment: you just added `die`, I told you to **dump** it as in my comment.

Comment: I just noticed and fixed it right away
but the problem is still the same http://prntscr.com/u1drmx

Comment: Ok but what does it give you when you click on your save button, **true** or **false** ? It is to know, if you are getting something from your form.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/u1dvb4
I delete the 28th parameter but the problem persists